# Read all cards from a project in Jira

Tags: javascript, java, jira

Is there a way to read all the cards that I have in Jira for a period?
My goal is to create a report with a number of cards that I have in REVIEW, the number of cards that I have in DONE and so on. I want to read the columns and know how many cards I have it.

It could be a script in JAVA or JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: Java doesn’t support scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this post from the JIRA/Atlassian community: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/REST-Client-get-all-issues-of-project/qaq-p/494826

Basically, you can use the REST endpoint `/rest/api/2/search?jql=project="Your Project Key"`. This will return issues for whichever project you specify.

There is a wealth of documentation and knowledge on JIRA's API [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/)

Answer (score 0):

If the only information you need is a number of issues per status you can simply create a pie chart gadget for this. Because you want to display issues for a specific timeframe you will have to create a [JQL filter first](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracorecloud/saving-your-search-as-a-filter-765593721.html), then open existing or [create a new dashboard](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/configuring-dashboards-764478209.html) (you need to be a dashboard administrator in order to add gadgets, you can become one by creating a new dashboard), then [add a pie chart gadget](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/adding-the-pie-chart-gadget-720417035.html), as a statistic type choose **Status**.

To find only the issues you are assigned to and that were updated within the specific time frame you need to create a search filter like:

```
assignee = currentUser() and updated > "2018/08/01"
```

this will find only the issues that are assigned to you and were updated after 2018/08/01.

The resulting chart will look like: 
[image]